# Override python statement during unit testing

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have 2 python program. one is main.py and another one is test_main.py
This is my main program(folder location ut3/ut)

```
ut3/ut$ vi main.py
def functiona():
    print("function a  ***")
    functionb()
 
 
def functionb():
    print("function b  ***")
    functionc()
 
 
def functionc():
    print("function c  ***")
 
 
def fn_main():
    functiona()
```

This is my unit test file (folder location: ut3)

```
ut3$ vi test_main.py
 
from ut import main
 
main.fn_main()
```

When I execute the test_main.py, it execute all the functions in the main.py program.
My requirement is :

first function: I want to call and execute only functiona(). Is there a way to override (or to remove the statement for functionb) ?
second function: Need to call only functionc. I can achieve this in the next statement using main.functionc().

Answer (score 0):

The following refactor makes your code testable as you requested by making it more modular:

```py
def functiona():
    print("function a  ***")


def functionb():
    print("function b  ***")


def functionc():
    print("function c  ***")


def functionabc():
    functiona()
    functionbc()


def functionbc():
    functionb()
    functionc()


def fn_main():
    functionabc()
```

Then you can separately test all functions in your unit test.